# how to add a parameter in listbox request ms-access

Tags: ms-access, request

I have a request with a a prameter

```
Select * from mytable where id = myparam
```

I'd like tout use this request to fill m'y listbox but I dont know how tout add m'y request parameter.
This param is a field of the form where m'y listbox is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to a form in a query string:

```
 Select * from mytable where id = Forms!TheFormNameHere!TheFieldOrControlNameHere
```

It is generally best to refer to a control name rather than a field name.